# Displaying Terms with Empty Descriptions

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I'm trying to display a list of terms from a single vocabulary that have blank descriptions. I'm using views, and I've tried to set up some regexes as filters. A simple: [\w] returns all of the non-blank ones. However, when I try to do something like ((?!.*[\w]).)* which should negate the string, I get some sql errors. I tried filtering with not containing certain words (i.e. any words), and I tried "shorter than" 1, but it seems that the truly empty description fields don't show up on any of these.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,}$ - Any word of at least one letter, number or _(not empty string)

^[\s]*$ - Truly empty string

Working for mee.